# Different levels of accuracy for three classes in naive bayes

Tags: naivebayes

I am new to machine learning. I am classifying tweets in three classes using term frequency feature. My training and test data are balanced for all classes and it's ratio is 70-30% for all classes. But accuracy for all three classes is so different like class one high.. 92% accurate, class two medium.. 53% accurate and class three very low.. 15% accurate.
Can anyone please tell what can possibly be wrong with my algorithm? 
I have three classes information neutral and metaphor.

```
`# Create term document matrix
tweets.information.matrix <- t(TermDocumentMatrix(tweets.information.corpus,control = list(wordLengths=c(4,Inf))));
tweets.metaphor.matrix <- t(TermDocumentMatrix(tweets.metaphor.corpus,control = list(wordLengths=c(4,Inf))));
tweets.neutral.matrix <- t(TermDocumentMatrix(tweets.neutral.corpus,control = list(wordLengths=c(4,Inf))));
tweets.test.matrix <- t(TermDocumentMatrix(tweets.test.corpus,control = list(wordLengths=c(4,Inf))));`
```

and that is how it calculates the probability

```
     `probabilityMatrix <-function(docMatrix)
{
  # Sum up the term frequencies
  termSums<-cbind(colnames(as.matrix(docMatrix)),as.numeric(colSums(as.matrix(docMatrix))))
  # Add one
  termSums<-cbind(termSums,as.numeric(termSums[,2])+1)
  # Calculate the probabilties
  termSums<-cbind(termSums,(as.numeric(termSums[,3])/sum(as.numeric(termSums[,3]))))
  # Calculate the natural log of the probabilities
  termSums<-cbind(termSums,log(as.numeric(termSums[,4])))
  # Add pretty names to the columns
  colnames(termSums)<-c("term","count","additive","probability","lnProbability")
  termSums
}
```

`

results for information are highly accurate , for neutral moderately accurate nad for Metaphor results are very low

Comment: Could you include the algorithm, or at least some code to help explain your question?

Comment: yes I put some code if it makes sense?

Comment: how is accuracy measured here? do you have a confusion matrix? can you provide precision % vs recall % for each class?

Comment: Recall for class1 is 95%, Class 2 is 57% and class 3 is 16%. And Precision for class1 is 69%, class2 is 39% and class3 is 100%

Comment: I believe everything is fine (at least in the code) then. Possibly your classifier lacks great features to predict class 2 and particularly class 3. It overly predicts class 1 (high recall, average precision), while almost never predict class 3. The tasks sounds difficult given their names. Maybe you need a larger dataset, or play with feature selection (stop word removal, keep more or fewer features, etc.)

Comment: No matter how difficult the task is, my algorithm is fed with the same amount of training data for all the classes.....I just looking for a possible reason if not the solution!!

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more about feature selection? Right now I have term frequency as one feature to predict the class. What can be other possible features? I am already removing punctuation, hashtag etc.

Comment: Even if the number of documents for each class in the training is the same, it doesn't mean they will have the same accuracy. When a classification class is difficult (few good class predictors), naive bayes will often overpredict a category (here it seems to be overpredicting class 1). Maybe because the prior of class 1 is a bit higher, maybe because class 2 and class 3 have more feature overlap, etc.